# How to increase Java and cplex memory usage

Tags: java, cplex

We developed a Java code and use cplex to solve a lp model.

We encounter to memory error.

When we increase cplex memory usage with `-Xmx1450` command line option, we received cplex out of memory error and when decrease it java give heap space error. we have 6GB memory and CPU Intel i7 950.

Memory usage never increases to above 38 percent and we cant increase `-Xmx`  above `1450`.
error occurs while constructing model(add constraint).

Comment: What is cplex? Please edit your question. And also tell us which OS you're using and what version of Java.

Comment: Why can't you increase it above 1450m? Do you have a 32-bit JVM? Are you sure its not trying to use all the memory when its gets an OutOfMemoryError?  Can you trigger a HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError to see how big the heap is and what is using the space?

Comment: What kind of OOM is it? PermGen?  There is more than one -X argument which affects JVM memory allocation.

Comment: You may be able to save some memory usage during model creation. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21400051#item2

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that cplex catches the Java `OutOfMemoryError` and displays its own error instead. So the two errors are basically the same but happen at different stages.

What you need is a 64bit OS and a 64bit versions of Java. That will allow you to give Java more memory.

Comment: we test it on windows xp 32bit and 64 bit also java 32 bit and 64 bit. cplex is an optimization software. it is 32 bit

Comment: Both the OS and Java must support 64bit - then you can give Java more memory.

Comment: in this case we give a error that cplex cant construct a dll file in 64bit mode

Comment: Ah, here we go. You need the 64bit version of "cplex", too.

Comment: Use a more simple model or wait until IBM releases a 64bit version.

Comment: @mehdifallahi CPLEX [does](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27019061) have a 64-bit version on most platforms.  It has had them for years.  CPLEX is a library, it doesn't "construct" any dll files.